# Is there any documentation for implementing forgot password feature in Django

Tags: python, django, email, passwords

I would like to implement a "forgot password" function, and at that point an email would be sent so that she would be able to change her own password. I have not found documentation on this. Someone could show me a way. Thanks for listening!

Comment: The [**`PasswordResetView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView)?

Comment: The simplest way is to use [`django-allauth`](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tyBEsHSv7w&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=12) on YouTube by Corey Schafer